# Site restricts too much for new users to do things properly

Tags: support

So I asked this question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/120650/apm-power-issue

And It was put on hold because it needed clarification. Ok. I wanted to comment to ask specifically what needs clarification. Not enough rep.

I then went to Meta Electrical Engineering to ask what needs to be changed and I need 5 rep.

So, how am I supposed to ask for the required changes?

Comment: There is no reputation requirement to comment on your own question.  You would have had to have been using a different account for that restriction to be in place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The close message is:

> "Questions on the repair of consumer electronics, appliances, or other devices must involve specific troubleshooting steps and demonstrate a good understanding of the underlying design of the device being repaired. See also: Is asking on how to fix a faulty circuit on topic?"

It was put on hold because it is off-topic, not because it is not clear.

---

> So, how am I supposed to ask for the required changes?

In this case, I don't see how you could salvage the question. Gaining 4 reputation points (you start with 1) is not difficult - two accepted suggested edits would get you there.